# Filtering blast results by evalue but only if unique

Tags: bash, awk, blast

I am working on a pipeline that at some point generates hundred of different files in the following format (I write X in the fields that I don't care about):

```
 id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  evalue1   X
 id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  evalue2   X     
 ...
```

I have to filter this file to, for each ID, take the best result based on the evalue (the smaller the better) but do not count that ID if the best evalue is repeated with the same ID.

As example if the input file is:

```
 id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
 id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-04   X
 id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X     
 id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-04   X     
 id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-04   X     
 id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  1e-02   X
```

The expected output would be:

```
 id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
 id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
```

Between the two hits for the id1 the worst is removed and as id3 best evalue is not unique that ID is not stored.

I have tried tunning blast command line tool but the closest option is setting the maximum number of hits to 1 but then cases like id3 remain in the output. So my solution was a python script but the amount of files make the process really time consuming.

Is there a way to filter this files with bash tools (awk?) to be efficient enough?

Each file has unique identifiers so the same ID cannot appear in more than one file.

Thanks in advance

**Update 1:**

Here the sample file:

```
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1104:7340:77245  gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|    100.00  24      0       0       1       24      529212  529189  3e-07   44.6
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:2303:18019:72377 gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|    100.00  20      0       0       1       20      622755  622736  2e-05   37.4
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:2103:11030:25200 gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|    95.24   21      1       0       1       21      321813  321833  3e-04   33.7
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:2103:11030:25200 gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|    95.24   21      1       0       1       21      495963  495943  3e-04   33.7
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:2103:11030:25200 gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|    95.00   20      1       0       2       21      613871  613852  0.001   31.9
```

After using the solution suggested by @karafka the output is:

```
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:2303:18019:72377 gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|   100.00  20  0   0   1   20  622755  622736  2e-05   37.4
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:2103:11030:25200 gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|   95.00   20  1   0   2   21  613871  613852  0.001   31.9
 D00733:159:CA65UANXX:8:1104:7340:77245  gi|13507739|ref|NC_000912.1|   100.00  24  0   0   1   24  529212  529189  3e-07   44.6
```

It seems that for the last id takes the 0.001 as minimum.

I am using GNU Awk 3.1.5

**Update 2**:

Enforcing numerical conversion doesn't fix the problem in awk 3.1.5, only solution: Update awk to >= 3.1.8

Comment: can't replicate your results.  I still get two records.  Perhaps the old version has some peculiarities.  You can enforce numerical conversion by adding 0.

Comment: No problem ;) thanks for your time

Comment: Works as expected in GNU Awk 3.1.8, but the output is wrong in 3.1.5 version...

Comment: time to upgrade )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '!($1 in min) || $11<min[$1] {min[$1]=$11; line[$1]=$0} 
     END {for(k in line) print line[k]}' file

 id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
 id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
 id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-04   X
```

this doesn't depend on the order of the entries, but also output order not guaranteed.

Another solution with `sort` assist

```
sort -k1,1 -k11g file | awk '!a[$1]++'

 id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
 id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
 id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-04   X
```

to print only if the minimum is unique

```
awk '!($1 in min) || $11<=min[$1] {min[$1]=$11; line[$1]=$0; c[$1,$11]++}
    END {for(k in line) if(c[k,min[k]]==1) print line[k]}' file

 id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
 id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X
```

to enforce numerical conversion you can add `0` to value ($11). For example

```
... $11+0<=min[$1] {min[$1]=$11+0; line[$1]=$0; c[$1,$11+0]++}...
```

Comment: Nice! Both options satisfy the first condition of taking the best but in the case of the id3 it should return nothing as the best evalue is not unique, any way to modify that?

Comment: That's what I need! Thanks

Comment: Why if one of the numbers has no 'e' float notation it takes the value without it as minimum? Example, if we add an additional id3 with evalue 0.01, it returns: 
`id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  0.01   X`

Comment: shouldn't  matter, we are comparing numbers, regardless of format.

Comment: Thats what I thought but if my input is:       

```
id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X         
id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X       
id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  0.001   X         
id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-04   X           
id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-04   X              
```

Last solution returns:

```
id1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X           
id2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  3e-07   X            
id3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X  0.001   X
```

Comment: it's not even the minimum even if the count keys were different.  Can you post the sample file (update your question) with that entry.  Also your `awk` version?